# OData Complex type in navigation property is null when expanded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I have the following structure

```
public class Relationship
{
    public Guid RelationshipId { get; set; }

    public Guid LeadObjectId { get; set; }

    public Guid MemberObjectId { get; set; }

    public Object LeadObject { get; set; }

    public Object MemberObject { get; set; }
}

public class Object
{
    public Guid ObjectId { get; set; }

    public ObjectDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectDetail
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
}
```

Here `Relationship` and `Object` are entities, with `Relationship` having navigation properties to `Object` via `LeadObject` and `MemberObject`. `Object` having a complex property `Detail` with complex type `ObjectDetail`.

I am using Entity Framework Core as my ORM in conjuction with Asp.net core odata.

My EF configuration for `Relationship` is

```
        protected override void ConfigureEntity(EntityTypeBuilder<Relationship> builder)
        {
            // omitted

            builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Detail, b =>
            {
                b.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnName("Status");
            });
        }
```

and for `Object`

```
        protected override void ConfigureEntity(EntityTypeBuilder<Object> builder)
        {
            // omitted

            builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Detail, b =>
            {
                b.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnName("Status");
            });
        }
```

Everything seems to be fine. When I request objects I can see the `Detail` property and I can see it has been set up as a complex type.

```
        <ComplexType Name="ObjectDetail">
            <Property Name="Status" Type="Namespace.ModelItemStatus" Nullable="false" />
        </ComplexType>
```

However, when I request relationships, and I expand one of the navigation object properties, e.g. `/relationships?$expand=LeadObject`, then complex detail property is null:

```
{
    "RelationshipId": "",
    "LeadObjectId": "",
    "MemberObjectId": "",
    "LeadObject": {
        "ObjectId": "",
        "Detail": null
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why, the configuration seems fairly simple and sensible, and seems to be set up fine.

HOWEVER, if I then `$select` the detail property on the expanded object, I then see it! So with this `/relationships?$expand=LeadObject($select=Detail)` I can see the detail:

```
{
    "RelationshipId": "",
    "LeadObjectId": "",
    "MemberObjectId": "",
    "LeadObject": {
        "Detail": {
            "Status": "CanSeeThisNow"
        }
    }
}
```

Why??

Comment: Wild guess but since no one has responded yet; Have you tried setting the MaxExpansionDepth on the Queryable attribute to anything above the default (2), to see if it makes any difference? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value